# E-store automatic email send, to be run daily

Tags: c#, .net, email

This is a fictional email sending program for a e-store I've done for practice purposes. `EmailSenderProgram` is a program sending emails to customers. Currently it sends two types of email: "welcome" and "please come back" email. It's supposed to run daily and write a debug log each day if it worked or not.

I'm gonna add more email types later and tried to make it easy for you to later add more emails. I'm Kinda new to programming, but it seems to be working and I would love some improvement tips.

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace EmailSenderProgram
{
    internal class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// This application is run everyday
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args"></param>
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Send Welcomemail");
            bool success = DoEmailWork();

#if DEBUG

            Console.WriteLine("Send Comebackmail");
            success = DoEmailWork2("CompanyComebackToUs");
#else

            if (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.Equals(DayOfWeek.Monday))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Send Comebackmail");
                success = DoEmailWork2("CompanyComeBackToUs");
            }
#endif
```

Check if the sending went OK

```
if (success == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("All mails are sent, I hope...");
                }
```

Check if the sending was not going well...

```
if (success == false)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Oops, something went wrong when sending mail (I think...)");
                }
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Send Welcome mail
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public static bool DoEmailWork()
            {
                try
                {   

List<Customer> e = DataLayer.ListCustomers();


for (int i = 0; i < e.Count; i++)
                    {
```

If the customer is newly registered, one day back in time

```
if (e[i].CreatedDateTime > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))
                        {


System.Net.Mail.MailMessage m = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();

                            m.To.Add(e[i].Email);
Add subject
                            m.Subject = "Welcome as a new customer at Company!";
Send mail from company@info.com
                            m.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("compay@info.com);

m.Body = "Hi " + e[i].Email +
                                     "<br>We would like to welcome you as customer on our site!<br><br>Best Regards,<br>Company Team";
    #if DEBUG
```

Don't send mails in debug mode, just write the emails in console

```
Console.WriteLine("Send mail to:" + e[i].Email);
    #else
Create a SmtpClient to our smtphost: yoursmtphost
                        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("yoursmtphost");
                    smtp.Send(m);
#endif
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Send Customer ComebackMail
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="v"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static bool DoEmailWork2(string v)
        {
            try
            {
                //List all customers 
                List<Customer> e = DataLayer.ListCustomers();
                //List all orders
                List<Order> f = DataLayer.ListOrders();

                //loop through list of customers
                foreach (Customer c in e)
                {
                    // We send mail if customer hasn't put an order
                    bool Send = true;
                    //loop through list of orders to see if customer don't exist in that list
                    foreach (Order o in f)
                    {
                        // Email exists in order list
                        if (c.Email == o.CustomerEmail)
                        {
                            //We don't send email to that customer
                            Send = false;
                        }
                    }

                    //Send if customer hasn't put order
                    if (Send == true)
                    {
                        //Create a new MailMessage
                        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage m = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
                        //Add customer to reciever list
                        m.To.Add(c.Email);
                        //Add subject
                        m.Subject = "We miss you as a customer";
                        m.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("company@info.com");
                        //Add body to mail
                        m.Body = "Hi " + c.Email +
                                 "<br>We miss you as a customer. Our shop is filled with nice products. Here is a voucher that gives you 50 kr to shop for." +
                                 "<br>Voucher: " + v +
                                 "<br><br>Best Regards,<br>Company Team";
#if DEBUG
                        //Don't send mails in debug mode, just write the emails in console
                        Console.WriteLine("Send mail to:" + c.Email);
#else
Create a SmtpClient to our smtphost: yoursmtphost
                        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("yoursmtphost");

                        smtp.Send(m);
    #endif
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Second class, a file with just the datalayers.

```
namespace EmailSenderProgram
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
    }

    public class Order
    {
        public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }
        public DateTime OrderDatetime { get; set; }
    }

    class DataLayer
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Mockup method for all customers
        /// </summary>
        public static List<Customer> ListCustomers()
        {
            return new List<Customer>()
                       {
                           new Customer(){Email = "mail1@mail.com", CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-7)}, 
                           new Customer(){Email = "mail2@mail.com", CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)}, 
                           new Customer(){Email = "mail3@mail.com", CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6)}, 
                           new Customer(){Email = "mail4@mail.com", CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1)}, 
                           new Customer(){Email = "mail5@mail.com", CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2)},
                           new Customer(){Email = "mail6@mail.com", CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5)}
                       };
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Mockup method for listing all orders
        /// </summary>
        public static List<Order> ListOrders()
        {
            return new List<Order>()
                       {
                           new Order(){CustomerEmail = "mail3@mail.com", OrderDatetime = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6)}, 
                           new Order(){CustomerEmail = "mail5@mail.com", OrderDatetime = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2)},  
                           new Order(){CustomerEmail = "mail6@mail.com", OrderDatetime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2)}
                       };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see *[What to do when someone answers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*. I have rolled back Rev 4 → 2.

Comment: Rolled back Rev 6 → 2, again. If you want feedback on your revised code, please post a follow-up question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are good and bad things about the code, but I will focus on some things that I believe to be bad about the code.

- The `EmailSenderProgram` namespace should be called `EmailSender`.
- You make an assumption that the program  is run exactly once a day.  What happens if it is run twice or not at all on a particular day?  You can solve this by including a `bool IsWelcomeEmailSent` on the `Customer` class and updating it.  Or even better adding a `CustomerEmails` store.
- `This application is run everyday` is a bad comment.  What happens if the business requirement changes and now it only runs once a week?  You should state what the program actually does.  For example `This application sends emails to customers.`.
- `DoEmailWork` and `DoEmailWork2` are bad function names.  Instead explain the purpose of the function, for example `SendWelcomeEmails` and `SendRetentionEmails`.
- If the `DoEmailWork` function returns false, it will set `bool success` to false.  Then if the `DoEmailWork2` function returns true, it will overwrite `bool success` to true.  Use 2 separate variables.
- The use of debug code, `#if DEBUG` etc, is pretty weird to be honest.  You are essentially writing test code into the code itself which is bad practice.  Instead you should be using unit testing, injecting all your dependencies so that they can be mocked.  This would allow you to mock the datasource as you are already doing, but then when you move to the real database, the code won't need to change.  This is a large subject on it's own and beyond the scope of this answer, but research *unit testing*, *dependency injection* and *mocking*.
- Give variables descriptive names.  `List<Customer> e = DataLayer.ListCustomers();` should be `var customers = DataLayer.ListCustomers();`.  Then instead of `for (int i = 0; i < e.Count; i++)`, use `foreach (var customer in customers)`.
- Which brings me onto inconsistent looping.  In `DoEmailWork` there is a `for` loop, but in `DoEmailWork2` there is a `foreach` loop.  This is confusing.
- There is duplication of the send email code.  Instead of building up the `MailMessage` object in each function, you should have general `SendEmail(List<string> recipients, string from, string subject, string body)` function that you call from the other functions.

There are other considerations to be made but I think you have enough to start of with.  You should also look into *Entity Framework* so that you can store your data in a database.  This will all mesh together with *Unit Testing*, *Dependency Injection* and *Mocking* over time.  This is a lot of information but I hope it helps you further improve your code.

EDIT

Here is an example of a possible SendEmail method.

```
using System.Net.Mail;

public void SendEmail(List<string> recipients, string from, string subject, string body)
{
    var mailMessage = new MailMessage();
    mailMessage.To = string.Join(",", recipients);
    mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(from);
    mailMessage.Subject = subject;
    mailMessage.Body = body;
}
```

And you can call it like this.

```
SendEmail(
    new List<string>() { "some@toemail.com", "another@toemail.com" },
    "amazing@fromemail.com",
    "the subject",
    "the super amazing body text and html"
);
```

Or using your data layer.

```
SendEmail(
    DataLayer.ListCustomers().SelectMany(customer => customer.Email),
    "amazing@fromemail.com",
    "the subject",
    "the super amazing body text and html"
);
```

You probably want to add a `.Where(customer => customer.CreatedDateTime > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))` after `ListCustomers()` aswell.  Then just wrap that function in an appropriately named function.

```
public void SendWelcomeEmails()
{
    foreach (var customer in DataLayer.ListCustomers()
                .Where(customer => customer.CreatedDateTime > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)))
    {
        SendEmail(
            customer.Email,
            "amazing@fromemail.com",
            "the subject",
            $"welcome {customer.Email}, this is the super amazing body text and html"
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Great tips, thanks for the help. Already started to implement most of them, unit testing will take a lot longer to implement though. I had on question so far, what do you mean with " Or even better adding a CustomerEmails store."? What is a store?

Comment: I used the word store in a generic sense, the store might be a database, in memory store or something else.  In practice I mean add a CustomerEmail class, and then store each email sent in there.  Then when deciding whether to send an email you can check whether it has already been sent or not.  And you will have an audit trail of the exact emails sent, including the variables.

Comment: How do you call on the function with a list as a parameter?

Comment: You need to pass a list of email addresses into that parameter, but if there is only one email address you still need to pass a list.  So you could create a list and add that email.

Comment: But how do I do that? I already have a list in the datalayer with my emails, how do I enter those into the function? @gamesmad

Comment: Hang on, I'll update the answer.

Comment: AH, I see. I lacked the new List<string>() in order to call your method. Is it possible to remove the recipients part and connect it to my datalayer customer emails as I did previously, but with the method? @gamesmad

Comment: Please see latest edit.

Comment: mailMessage.to gave an error so I put the whole thing into an foreach loop like this foreach (Customer customer in customers) and changed mailMessage.To.Add(customer.Email); instead and it worked. Is this valid?

Comment: Change it to be - mailMessage.To.Add(string.Join(",", recipients));    Forgive me I didn't compile or run any of that code I wrote.  Post another question with the revised code if you want to go over it more.  Best of luck.

Comment: You should **never** send these types of messages with more than one email in the `To` or `CC` field. See [this article](https://techcrunch.com/2016/08/01/glassdoor-sued-by-user-whose-email-was-leaked-instead-of-bcced/) for an example of why. Use `Bcc` if you wan't to send the exact same email to several addresses.

Comment: What if a single Customer has multiple email addresses that are all opted in to communications?  Although you do make a very important point, accidentally leaking email addresses is extremely undesirable.  Take as much (or even more) care over a software driven email as you would when manually sending.